# Converting existing web gradient to transparent overlay of a single colour

Tags: css

What I'm trying to achieve is to change an existing web gradient using hex colour values to a web gradient that is just a black colour with opacity added to darken the background colour where needed.

So, convert this:

```
background-color: #76b347;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #76b347), color-stop(100%, #5e9e2e));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #76b347, #5e9e2e);
```

To something like this (but with the right values, so it looks the same):

```
background-color: #76b347;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
```

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: You say *so it looks the same*. But over which color? White?

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer. The background colour is specified, so over that colour - which is #76b347 in the code.